# Properly defining a chain of singleton classes

Tags: python, class, singleton

I am trying to create a `Token` class which takes initial values and pass the instance of it into a different class. this is my attempt using `Singleton` since I only want a single instance of the token per user session.

```
class Token(object):
      _instance = None

      def __new__(cls, *args, userName = None, password = None, tokenData = {}):
          if cls._instance is None:
              print('Creating the object')


              cls._instance = super(Token, cls).__new__(cls)
              cls._instance.userName =  userName
              cls._instance.password =  password
              cls._instance.tokenData = tokenData

          return cls._instance


    class UseResource():
       def __init__(Token):
           def acceptToken(Token):
                token = Token._instance()
                print( token.userName )
                accessResource(Token)


newtoken = Token(username='Rob', password='1234abcd', {type:auth, value:32, duration:3600} )
resource = UseResource(newtoken)
```

Is there a better way to initialize the class arguments?

Comment: No need to make `UseResource` a singleton too if `Token` is one because the single instance of latter will only create one of the former.

Comment: is my definition of the class attributes fine? `cls._instance.userName =  userName` etc.. and also am i making proper calls at the bottom of the code?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're doing from the line with `accessResource(` onward — it doesn't look like valid code.

Comment: You fixed it syntactically, but it doesn't make sense. `__init__()` methods don't return anything and generally aren't called directly. When you want to create an instance of a class (whether it's a singleton or not), you do so by calling **it** — i.e `newtoken = Token(......)`. Regardless, I still see no reason to make `UseResource` as singleton, too.

Comment: you re right, my mistake; wasnt paying attemntion